# yarn start fails after error in installing date-fns in react-native app

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

For date formatting I tried downloading date-fns through: `npm install date-fns --save`

Installation failed and I got following warnings and errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-expo@8.1.1: 8.1.1 mistakenly contains the contents of 8.2.1; use that version instead
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated intl-relativeformat@2.2.0: This package has been deprecated, please see migration guide at 'https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/tree/master/packages/intl-relativeformat#migration-guide'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\.bin\rimraf.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\.bin\rimraf as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\metro-core\node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN react-native-elements@2.0.2 requires a peer of react-native-vector-icons@>6.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

After that I left it there and saved the application without formatting the date and tried running `yarn start`, to which I get this output:

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nice-try'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\expo\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\parse.js
- C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\expo\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js
- C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\expo\bin\cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\expo\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\parse.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\kanch\\Documents\\ReactNative\\confusion\\node_modules\\expo\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\parse.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kanch\\Documents\\ReactNative\\confusion\\node_modules\\expo\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kanch\\Documents\\ReactNative\\confusion\\node_modules\\expo\\bin\\cli.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I am unable to start Metro server and can't find `nice-try` in my node_modules. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and then `npm install?`

Comment: No, but do you mean deleting the node_modules whole folder? And I did `create-react-native-app` using yarn so, does this question have something to do with that?

Comment: Yes, node_modules whole folder. Since there was an issue for npm install date-fns --save, So it might have corrupted some dependency tree.
So deleting it and doing fresh yarn install should clean and reinstall it.

Comment: It worked but I lost the .bin folder in node_modules and this error is popping out on the android phone:
```React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version: 0.63.1
Native version: 0.62.2
```
And  when running on web browser it fails to compile displaying:
```Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/DatePickerAndroid' in 'C:\Users\kanch\Documents\ReactNative\confusion\node_modules\react-native-datepicker```

How to solve these?

Comment: Are you using npm install or yarn install?
npm install creates a file named package-lock.json whereas yarn install creates yarn.lock file these preserves the last version install.
So you have to delete these 2 files with node_modules then use either yarn or npm for package installation. Do not use both.
Try doing it hopefully it will resolve the issue of versioning.

Comment: Okay! I am using yarn to install packages but in the last installation I used npm, that may have caused all that earlier errors. I am installing all the packages by referring to package.json file.